# Why my mesh doesn't look "solid"?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, extrude

Hey guys I'm new to blender and I'm working on something; I apologize in advance if things that don't make sense but here goes:

I'm trying to extrude they eyes of my model, I am currently watching a tutorial and when he extrudes his model looks like the following:

[image]

however when I do it,my extrude looks fairly different; I select the verticies I want, I push E and then use S to scale it to how I want it and unlike the above image my extrude looks more "meshy" than it does "solid".
This is Mine (ny Idea how to make it look like the one above?:

[image]

plz help this has been bugging me for the longest time. I can't find solutions this is my last hope lol

Comment: Looks about the same to me, only difference is in the shading, could it be from the viewport viewing mode? Try pressing Z to switch to shaded mode or switch it from the menu the one with the sphere) in the 3D view header at the bottom of the window, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are in Wireframe view.

Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle Wireframe view. Alternatively, select the small sphere down on the bottom, and then select Solid to go back to the default view.

[image: Dropdown]

Comment: @bash Glad to be of a help. Enjoy blender and have fun!